# Retrieving text on focusout/blur

Tags: javascript, jquery, text, focus, textarea

I have mulitple textarea's, when you're finished editing them i'm looking to retrieve the new text when the field doesn't have focus anymore.

The solution i've been trying is

```
$('textarea').live('focusout', function() {
console.log(this.text);
});

or

$('textarea').live('blur', function() {
console.log(this.text);
});
```

Both return as undefined, due to it not knowing what 'this' is referring to.

Is there another event that can make this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the `value` property (`this.value`) to get the contents. Even in JQuery, the `.text()` method doesn't return the right contents of a textarea.

If you want to use a JQuery method:

```
$('textarea').live('focusout', function() {
    console.log($(this).val());
}
```